# HTTP basic authentication over Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, basic-authentication

I am trying to use HTTP Basic Authentication over Devise for my Rails app. I have done following settings ->
`config.http_authenticatable = true` in the devise initializer
And
`:database_authenticatable` strategy in my USER model.

When I try to access a web service
mysite.com/user/list.json?email=test@mysite.com&password=test123

The username password is not recognized. A credentials box pops up where on entering the credentials I am authenticated to use the data.

How can I provide the credentials in the URL and avoid the pop up prompt?

Comment: Information in a URL is passed through a GET Method and information like logging in is passed through a POST method - for security, I don't believe you should be able to do what you want to do actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this-->

http://username:password@test.com/users/list.json?

Comment: Yes, this will work too. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Basic Auth, is passed through HTTP Headers, not GET or POST params.